# play framework application hosting in a application server

Tags: scala, playframework, web-hosting

I have done my project using scala and play framework. Now I need to know clearly how to deploy my application to a server. what are the things I install to my server except java. I`m new in web application hosting. If anybody has experienced in this please help me. I have refer this article [Production](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Production) and build the .zip file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Play framework has a in-build Netty Server, you can this or use any Java application server to run your application.

For Netty Server:
Unzip the build zip and transverse to bin and execute bat or sh file.

For Other Application Servers:
Refer the following link:
https://github.com/play2war/play2-war-plugin

Comment: how can I setup Netty server in my application server?

Comment: You don't need to setup Netty Server in your application server. Netty Server is an independent server available with Play framework.
For more information, please refer : http://jto.github.io/articles/play_anatomy_part1_bootstrap/